Google AdMob RewardedAd renders close button beneath the status bar on iOS
The Rewarded Ad is occassionally stretching to the edges of the display on an iPhone and ignoring the safe area. This results in the close button to render in the same spot as the control center trigger thus making it impossible to tap on the close button. (Please refer to the screenshot).
Here is the code snippet that is used to show the Rewarded Ad -
extension UIApplication {
    
    var keyWindow: UIWindow? {
        connectedScenes
            .compactMap {
                $0 as? UIWindowScene
            }
            .flatMap {
                $0.windows
            }
            .first {
                $0.isKeyWindow
            }
    }
    
    public var rootViewController: UIViewController? {
        guard let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow, let rootViewController = keyWindow.rootViewController else {
            return nil
        }
        return rootViewController
    }
    
    public func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        
        if controller == nil {
            return topViewController(controller: rootViewController)
        }
        
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selectedViewController = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selectedViewController)
            }
        }
        
        if let presentedViewController = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presentedViewController)
        }
        
        return controller
    }
}

guard let currentUiViewController = UIApplication.shared.topViewController() else { return }
rewardedAd.present(fromRootViewController: currentUiViewController) {
     let reward = rewardedAd.adReward
     self.rewardAdPlaybackCallbacks?.onUserEarnedReward(rewardAdHandle: self.currentRewardAdHandle!)
}

I have also attempted to change the safe area behaviour for the currentUiViewController and tried both ways, first, where the safe area is ignored and second, where the safe area is respected. The issue has occurred in both scenarios.
Is there a way to fix or address this issue? Any tips or suggestions would be most helpful. Thanks in advance!


You will have to hide status bar before presenting ad and show it after closing ad.
Steps to hide/unhide status bar

Set View controller-based status bar appearance to YES in info.plist

In the view controller you are presenting the rewarded ad add below code
 var isStatusBarHidden = false {
     didSet {
         setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
     }
 }

 override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
     return isStatusBarHidden
 }


Hide status bar before presenting rewarded ad
 // Hide the status bar
 isStatusBarHidden = true
 rewardedAd.present(fromRootViewController: currentUiViewController) {
     let reward = rewardedAd.adReward
     self.rewardAdPlaybackCallbacks?.onUserEarnedReward(rewardAdHandle: 
     self.currentRewardAdHandle!)
 }


Unhide status bar in ad delegate GADFullScreenContentDelegate
 func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
     // Show the status bar again
     isStatusBarHidden = false
 }

 func adDidFailToPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, error: Error) {
     // Show the status bar again if the ad fails to present
     isStatusBarHidden = false
 }



If the viewcontroller is in UINavigationController create a extension like below
   extension UINavigationController {

       open override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
           return topViewController?.prefersStatusBarHidden ?? false
       }

       open override var childForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
           return topViewController
       }
  }

